# Is there a vim command that swap two words with crossing one operator?

Tags: vim

For example, Guess I have this block.

```
if( first > second)
{
}
```

And I want to swap these words with crossing one operator.

```
if( second > first)
{
}
```

How to do with vim command naturally?

Comment: There are actually 3 words including the `>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to do that manually you could do the following (with the cursor on `first`):

```
yiw    yank current word
ww     move cursor to 'second'
viw    visually select current word
p      put from unnamed register (selected word goes to unnamed register)
bbb    move cursor back to 'first'
viw    visually select current word
p      put from unnamed register
```

which is relatively intuitive but, admittedly, quite involving.

You could probably map that to some easy to type key-combination:

```
nnoremap <key> yiwwwviwpbbbviwp
```

but you may end up having to fight against corner case after corner case.

Or you could put this snippet (found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines#Mappings)) in your `vimrc` and simply press `<key1>` to swap the current "word" with the previous and `<key2>` to swap the current "word" with the next:

```
nnoremap <key1>  "_yiw?\v\w+\_W+%#<CR>:s/\v(%#\w+)(\_W+)(\w+)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o><C-l>
nnoremap <key2> "_yiw:s/\v(%#\w+)(\_W+)(\w+)/\3\2\1/<CR><C-o>/\v\w+\_W+<CR><C-l>
```

Comment: It seems 'bbb' on 5th step.

Answer (score 5):

I have [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) plugin that allows me to change words in this way.

At the first word press `cxiw` then jump to the second word and press `.`

Answer (score 1):

Pending a more natural way to do it, how about this?

```
:map <f7> <esc>dbwPwdwbbPl<esc>
```

Place the cursor on `<` and press <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the following function:

```
function! Swap()
  normal di)
  let a=split(@")
  let @b=a[2]." ".a[1]." ".a[0]
  normal %"bp
endfunction
```

That can be mapped to `gs`, for example:

```
nnoremap <silent> gs :call Swap()<cr>
```

A drawback of this approach is that it is more involved than solutions based on mappigs. Its advantage is that it works by placing the cursor anywhere inside the parenthesis  `(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
" Swap two words
nmap <silent> gw :s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR>`'
```

1. Place your cursor at 1st letter `f` of first 
    `if( first > second)`
2. then press `gw` to swap between `first` and `second`

You will get your desired output `if( second > first)`